# Hide Input/Output in algorithm2e

Tags: algorithm2e

I'm making a Beamer presentation and I need space, so I want to hide the inputs and outputs and instead only show my algorithm. But when I simply don't write the input keyword, then the line numbers suddenly disappear:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    \LinesNumbered
    \SetKwInOut{Input}{Input} 
    \Input{} % can't omit this, else line numbers don't work ...
    line 1\;
    line 2\;
    line 3\;
    line 4\;
    line 5\;
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

With `\Input`:

[image]

Without it:

[image]

Note: in beamer directly the bug is weirder, as line number show, but are shifted vertically:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `linesnumbered` as an option to `algorithm2e`, it will work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
    \DontPrintSemicolon
    line 1\;
    line 2\;
    line 3\;
    line 4\;
    line 5\;
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting and weird that the global setting behaves differently than the per algorithm `\LinesNumbered`, but it works. Thank you. I guess you could do that and then where necessary use `\LinesNotNumbered`.

Comment: I am not very familiar with the `algorithm2e` package, but I guess you can use `\LinesNotNumbered` with the desired result. I don't see clearly why the local setting doesn't work while the global does.